# Writing images into a different folder

Tags: python, mscoco

I have two directories:

```
dir1 = path/to/original/imgs
```

and

```
dir2 = path/to/subset/imgs
```

dir1 contains images from COCO dataset, and dir2 is currently empty. I also have a list which contains the names of some images (extracted from dir1):

```
list1 = ['img1', 'img2', 'img3', 'img4', 'img5']
```

What I need to do is compare the names of the images from list1 to the names of images in dir1 and save the matching images into dir2. Following is what I have until now:

```
import os
path_to_imgs = "/path/to/dir1"
path_to_subset_imgs = "/path/to/dir2"
file_list = os.listdir(path_to_imgs)
for img_name in list1:
    for filename in file_list:
        if img_name == filename:
```

I am unable to understand how to proceed with saving the identical images into dir2. I checked [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32427999/python-compare-filenames-in-folder) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15069091/compare-directories-on-file-folder-names-only-printing-any-differences). Any help is highly appreciated. 
Thank You.

Comment: os.listdir returns filenames with extension, maybe you need to extract only the name ? `os.path.splitext()` can help

Comment: I only need to compare two images based on their names, yes; I will give `os.path.splitext()` a try. But I still need to save the images with matching names in dir2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider using [shutil](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/shutil.html)

```
import shutil

image_list = ['img1', 'img2', 'img3', 'img4', 'img5'] 
dirs_list = [("/path/to/dir1/", "/path/to/dir2/")]

for img in image_list:
    for source_folder, destination_folder in dirs_list:
        shutil.copy(source_folder+img, destination_folder+img)
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

first check if the image exists in the folder dir1 and the if it exists copy the image from the dir1 to dir2.

```
for img in list1:
    if os.path.exists(dir1+img):
        shutil.copy(dir1+img, dir2+img)
    else:
        print "Image %s doesn't exist"%img
```